# Trying to understand Java String implementation

Tags: java, string, size, primitive-types

I'm looking at the openjdk implementation of String and the private, per instance members look like:

```
public final class String
    implements java.io.Serializable, Comparable<String>, CharSequence
{
    /** The value is used for character storage. */
    private final char value[];

    /** The offset is the first index of the storage that is used. */
    private final int offset;

    /** The count is the number of characters in the String. */
    private final int count;

    /** Cache the hash code for the string */
    private int hash; // Default to 0

    [...]
}
```

But I know that Java uses reference and pools for Strings, to avoid duplication. I was naively expecting a pimpl idiom, where String would in fact be just a ref to an impl. I'm not seeing that so far. Can someone explain how Java will know to use references if I put a String x; member in one of my classes?

Addendum: this is probably wrong, but if I'm in 32 bits mode, should I count: 4 bytes for the reference "value[]", 4 bytes for offset, 4 for count and 4 for hash for everything instance of class String? That would mean that writing "String x;" in one of my class automatically adds at least 32 bytes to the "weight" of my class (I'm probably wrong here).

Comment: A String is a String. Whether it is pooled or not makes no difference to the nature of the String, only to where it is stored and optimisations that can be made around it.

Comment: A pimpl idiom? My guess would be that you are coming from a C++ background, and that you haven't appreciated how different Java's object model is from C++'s. Java isn't just badly-spelled C++, it's a very different language. I would urge you to read the [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/) to get a more detailed understanding of what Java is like.

Comment: Good guess! I'm a C++ guy. I have some experience with Java, but I find it pretty disconcerting.

Answer (score 3):

The offset/count fields are somewhat orthogonal to the pooling/`intern()` issues. Offset and count come when you have something like:

```
String substring = myString.substring(5);
```

One way to implement this method would be something like:

- allocate a new `char[]` with `myString.length() - 5` elements
- copy all of the elements from index index 5 to `myString.length()` from myString to the new `char[]`
- `substring` is constructed with this new `char[]`

  - `substring.charAt(i)` goes directly to `chars[i]`
  - `substring.length()` goes directly to `chars.length`

As you san see, this approach is O(N) -- where N is the new string's length -- and requires two allocations: the new String, and the new char[]. So instead, `substring` works by resusing the original char[] but with an offset:

- `substring.offset` = `myString.offset + newOffset`
- `substring.count` = `myString.count - newOffset`
- use `myString.chars` as the chars array for `substring`

  - `substring.charAt(i)` goes to `chars[i+substring.offset]`
  - `substring.length()` goes to `substring.count`

Note that we didn't need to create a new char[], and more importantly, we didn't need to copy the chars from the old char[] to the new one (since there is no new one). So this operation is just O(1) and requires only one allocation, that of the new String.

Comment: `So this operation is just O(N) and requires only one allocation, that of the new String.` This should say `O(1)`. Mistake gone over a year uncorrected! lol

Answer (score 2):

Java **always** uses references to any object. There's no way to make it not use references. As for string pooling, that is achieved by the compiler for string literals and at runtime by calling [`String.intern`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#intern%28%29). It is natural that most of the implementation of `String` is oblivious to whether it is dealing with an instance referred to by the constant pool or not.

Comment: String a = "a"; and String b = new String("a"); use two different memory models, as well.

Comment: If I look at the code I do see a reference: that of `value[]`. Do you know if that fact is used when interning a `String` or is it performed another way?

Comment: OK, so what is the weight of String x in my class? I'm counting 4 bytes for the reference value[] (on 32 bits), 4 for the offset, 4 for the count, 4 for the hash code, so is that 32 bytes?

Comment: @KevinMangold I have no idea what you mean by "memory model", but obviously you are not referring to anything like the Java Memory Model.

Comment: Frank, you must understand that the matters are just not that simple. Your class is not the owner of the `String` instance. The instance itself and, even more importantly, the backing `char[]`, is being shared around so the memory is reused.

Comment: If you want to know the memory consumption of a string, that'll be the 32 bytes you count, plus 8 bytes for the `String` object header and 12 bytes for the array header, and then of course the characters themselves.  (Also, to make it clear: @MarkoTopolnik's comments about the sharing of the `String` only apply to string literals and `intern()`'d strings.)

Comment: @Louis: are you saying that writing "String x;" (and nothing else) in a class, makes that class' memory weight += 32 + 8 + 12?

Comment: @LouisWasserman In general even this will not end the calculation because one must take into account memory alignment, which increases the count towards the nearest multiple of 8.

Comment: `String x;` introduces a null reference costing four bytes.  No actual `String` value exists yet, so that's the full extent of the cost.

Comment: @LouisWasserman Again subject to alignment, so introducing `String x` will either result in no increase, or in an increase of 8 bytes, the average being your 4 bytes.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Play around with Strings and see for yourself: http://www.xyzws.com/Javafaq/what-is-string-literal-pool/3 The way the JVM handles where and how strings are stored and used depends on how they are created.

Comment: @KevinMangold I didn't find the phrase "memory model" at that page. I'm still not enlightened as to what you mean by that.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik memory model = pooled vs. not pooled (I suppose)

Comment: The issue for me is that we have tight memory constraints, and we have some classes that contain 2 instance of String, some possibly never used. So, if somehow I refactored to have only 1 String (that I could parse to extract 2 pieces of data), I would only save 4 bytes a priori (the reference) when the second piece of data is not needed.

Comment: @LouisWasserman `char[]` sharing happens independently of interning. Even `new String(str)` will **not** guarantee you get a separate `char[]`.

Comment: @assylias Yes. I guess Marko and my definition of what a memory model is or can be is different.

Comment: Frank, exactly. An unused `String` reference will cost on average 4 bytes, but, as I said, may cost **nothing at all** if you don't cross the 8-byte alignment boundary. You would have to push the scenario very far indeed in order to experience the difference of one `String` reference more or less.

Comment: @KevinMangold So it seems you are using that term in a very loose sense, to the point of nothing in particular. Especially when we take into account structural sharing that goes on between strings, it is hard for me to imagine what is the "memory model" of strings in your sense where I should imagine two disparate memory models. If you said "memory layout" or "class design", that would've given me slightly more assurance as to what you meant by it. But, now that I (kind of) see what you mean, let's leave it alone.

Answer (score 1):

Java Strings are immutable. This means that the implementation can do a whole lot of things to the internal representation, without breaking any application code.

Note that the Java [`String.intern()`](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/lang/String.java.html) has been defined to be native in the JDK implementation of Oracle. *Native code has access to all fields of an object and may change the reference under water*. So all that the implementors have to do is to change the reference and offset to a location where the string is interned and voila. Of course this breaks the immutability of the class, so this means that the intern() update better be thread safe.

You could check what happens to the fields when you call `intern()` on a newly generated String. If nothing happens, it might be that the reference itself contains the memory location instead. The Java language specification does not define how references are implemented.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer and other answers are outdated.  After the Java 7 update 6, strings in Java no longer use offsets and are not tuned for substring optimization.  Instead, every substring creates a new copy of the string.

If you wanted to use the original string implementation, you'd have to use CharSequence.

For more information: https://jaxenter.com/the-state-of-string-in-java-107508.html